# How to assign two containers having different template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Let's suppose that I have a class container:

```
template<class T, int size>
class container
{
private:
    T* data;
    int length;
public:
    container()
    {
        data=new T[size];
        length=size;
    }
    ~container()
    {
        if(length>0)
            delete[] data;
    }
    container& operator= (container<T,size> c)
    {
        if(length>0)
           delete[] data;
        data=new T[c.length];
        length=c.length;
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
            data[i]=c.data[i];
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The problem is that if I have two container of different size, I can't use the = operator to assign one to the other.For example:

```
container<int,4> c1;
container<int,5> c2;
c1=c2;  // syntax error: 4!=5
```

Classes like c++11 array allow to do this.
How to do that?

Comment: Why is `size` a template parameter?  The _size_ of your `container` appears to be dynamic.

Comment: You don't just have two containers of different size, you have two objects with different template parameters - they're not compatible.  To the compiler, it's as if you tried to assign a container of ints to a container of floats.  Typically the length of a container is not a template parameter.

Comment: Remember a copy constructor. By making the size a template parameter, you're kind of messing up the point of using dynamic memory, too. You can't get the user to enter a size, for example.

Comment: C++11's `std::array` doesn't allow you to change the container's size, which is what you're attempting to do here.

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong, `std::array` doesn't allow you to assign from a different size `std::array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates are just that -- templates the compiler uses to make classes, not classes themselves.

Thus, `container<int,4>` and `container<int,5>` are completely separate classes, with all of the access restrictions that implies.

In particular, this means that `container<int, 4>`'s assignment operator cannot access the `private` memebers of `container<int,5>`.

There are a few ways to get around this:

- Eliminate the size template argument, since as others have noted, you seem to be allocating memory dynamically, so nailing down the size at compile time isn't adding any value, and in fact could be misleading since your assignment operator could result in a different size than the one declared.
- Implement your assignment operator in terms of `container`'s public interface.
- Declare all `container` classes of the same type as `friends` by adding the following line to your class:

Code:

```
template<class U, int otherSize> friend class Foo;
```

and declaring your assignment operator as follows:

```
template <int otherSize>
container<T,size>& operator=(container<T,otherSize> c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parametrize your assigment operator with size of container you want to assign from (*ignoring any other issues with posted code*):

```
    template <int otherSize>
    container& operator= (container<T,otherSize> c)
    {
        if(length>0)
           delete[] data;
        data=new T[otherSize];
        length=otherSize;
        for(int i=0; i<otherSize; i++)
            data[i]=c.data[i];
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: Won't compile, `data` is private. Other then that the only possible solution, although the problems stated in the question's comments still persist.

Comment: Obviously, since orginal code will not compile (also for this reason) ;)

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have pointed out, having the initial size be a template parameter looks wrong, and is the source of your problems.

But considering the general question of assigning from two incompatible containers, you could have a templated `operator=` as tumdum's answer shows, but that doesn't help when you want to fill the container from another, slightly-different type.

The standard containers solve the problem by allowing construction and assignment from a range, defined by a pair of iterators:

```
template<typename FwdIter>
  container(FwdIter begin, FwdIter end)
  {
    data=new T[length = std::distance(begin, end)];
    std::copy(begin, end, data);
  }

template<typename FwdIter>
  void
  assign(FwdIter begin, FwdIter end)
  {
    container(begin, end).swap(*this);
  }

void swap(container& c)
{
  std::swap(data, c.data);
  std::swap(length, c.length);
}

iterator begin() { return data; }
const_iterator begin() const { return data; }
const_iterator cbegin() const { return data; }
iterator end() { return data+size; }
const_iterator end() const { return data+size; }
const_iterator cend() const { return data+size; }
```

Now you can do:

```
container<int,4> c1;
container<int,5> c2;
c1.assign(c2.begin(), c2.end());
```